# Creating many albums using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

It's a rake task which searches for an artists and if it exists it will store it with artists albums. I've tried to use a [gem](https://github.com/rlivsey/itunes-search-api) but for some reason the gem returns something I don't really need. If I search an artist it works fine though.

```
result = ITunesSearchAPI.lookup(:id => 372976 , :entity => 'album')
```

will return this:

```
{"wrapperType"=>"artist", "artistType"=>"Artist", "artistName"=>"ABBA", "artistLinkUrl"=>"https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/abba/id372976?uo=4", "artistId"=>372976, "amgArtistId"=>3492, "primaryGenreName"=>"Pop", "primaryGenreId"=>14}
```

which is not what I need at all. [Here's](https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=372976&entity=album) what I should get.

So I decided to code it myself and then I realized that it saves an empty model, everything in my Album is nil.
2 questions:

1) How can I fix it?

2) How can I save ALL albums, not just one?

```
require 'net/http'

  task :artist,[""] => :environment do |t, args|
    result = ITunesSearchAPI.search(:term => args.to_s, :entity => 'musicArtist')
    if result.empty? then puts "Nothing was found. Try another artist."
      puts result
    elsif result
      uniqueness = Artist.find_by(itunes_id: result[0]["artistId"])
      if uniqueness.nil?
        Artist.create(name: result[0]["artistName"], itunes_id: result[0]["artistId"])
        puts result
      else
        puts "The artist already exists in database"
      end
    end
    if uniqueness.nil?
    album = URI('https://itunes.apple.com/lookup')
    album_params = { :id => result[0]['artistId'], :entity => 'album'}
    album.query = URI.encode_www_form(album_params)
    album_response = Net::HTTP.get_response(album)
    puts album_response.body
    Album.create!(name: album_response.body[0]["collectionName"], artwork_url_100: album_response.body[0]["artworkUrl100"])
  end
end
```

Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160418120725) do

  create_table "albums", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "artwork_url_100"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "artists", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "itunes_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "artists", ["itunes_id"], name: "index_artists_on_itunes_id", unique: true

end
```

Comment: Can you post the schema and model code for `Album`?

Comment: @AnthonyE Sure, updated the post. Album has belongs_to :artist
That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to part 1.** You probably need to add some model validations for uniqueness and presence. In your artist.rb file:

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  validates :itunes_id, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  ...
end
```

That should prevent your model being saved in an invalid state. Each attribute `itunes_id` and `name` must both be present (not nil) and unique (you cannot have 2 'ABBA' artist records).

More on ActiveRecord validation can be found at:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Once you've got your validation rules in place then your code to check for existing records and updating them can simplify to:

```
artist = Artist.where(itunes_id: result[0]["artistId"]).first_or_initialize
artist.name = result[0]["artistName"]
artist.save
```

Then we get to check for any errors that prevented the record from persisting to the database:

```
if artist.errors.any?
  puts "There were errors preventing the artist being saved:"
  artist.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
    puts " - #{message}"
  end
  puts "Result data: #{result}"
  exit
end
```

Once we are past this block (we haven't exited) then we know our `artist` object is a valid and persisted model object.

**Answer to part 2.** You need to have a one-to-many (has_many) association between the Artist and Album model. Then you just need to iterate through the results array creating a new Album for each entry.

Looking at your schema you need to add an integer attribute to the Album model called `artist_id`. You can create a migration with the command:

```
rails g migration AddArtistToAlbums artist:references
```

The *magic* command line syntax should generate a correct migration file that should look something like this:

```
class AddArtistToAlbums < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :albums, :artist, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Run a `rake db:migrate` to update the database schema.

In your artist.rb model file you can now add the the following:

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :albums
  ...
end
```

You can now access albums associated to an artist through it's association attribute `albums`.

In your album.rb model file you can now add the the following:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :artist
  ...
end
```

You can now access artist associated to an album through it's association attribute `artist`.

Before you dive straight in to interpreting the response body I would probably check to see if I got the right kind of request first:

```
if !album_response.is_a?(Net::HTTPOK)
  puts "There was an error fetching albums."
  exit
end
```

Before you can deal with the response you need to parse the JSON. At the top of the file at `require 'json'` then parse the `album_response.body` like:

```
album_response_json = JSON.parse(album_response.body)
```

After that I'd also check to make sure the body is populated as expected.

```
if !album_response_json.is_a?(Hash)
  puts "Response JSON is not a Hash as expected."
  exit
end
```

You can also check that the response hash has the expected `results` array.

```
if !album_response_json["results"].is_a?(Array)
  puts "Response JSON does not contain the expected 'results' array."
  exit
end
```

Next, you were accessing a key value from the hash by index `album_response.body[0]` which would be an integer (23) based on your example JSON. I think you meant to access the first element of the `results` array.

What you need to do is iterate over the results creating a new model object for each album. I noticed that in your example JSON response that there is a `wrapperType` of 'artist' which I presume you want to filter out so the code would look something like this:

```
album_response_json["results"].each do |album_hash|
  next if album_hash["wrapperType"] == "artist"
  artist.albums.create!(name: album_hash["collectionName"], artwork_url_100: album_hash["artworkUrl100"])
end
```

You should now have the albums stored as expected.

Note. I skipped past adding validations to the Album model but it would be a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for such a great answer. I did all you wrote and that's what I get now: 
"NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for "results":String"
It seems it doesn't know where to get results or something like that.

Comment: Sorry, I skipped passed the details on parsing the response body. I have updated the answer to show how to parse the response body as JSON. The error you got was do to the response body being a really big string, and string objects don't have an `each` method! Hope this works for you now.

Comment: Thank you so much, you made my day :]. I wish I could upvote you but I'll do it as soon as I get enough reputation.

Comment: @r0uder, I just noticed that you've now posted your schema so I've updated the the information on how to modify your schema to add the one-to-many relationship that I previously assumed you had.

Comment: Can't thank you enough man. Now it's all clear because of you.